# Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

How can I setup nginx as reverse proxy along with apache on CentOS 5.6

I have already install apache, but I dont know if I should proceed with installing nginx because I am afraid that may set nginx as the default server.

How do I proceed with the installation and set up configuration for nginx as a reverse proxy to serve static content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yum install nginx
```

then setup nginx config to listen to port 80
and create virtual domain files

change the apache port to whatever listening port was set in nginx virtual domains file

restart both and voila!

use this link-> http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy